# WSE 1.0 compatible with .net 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, upgrade

I'm currently upgrading my codes from .NET 1.1 to .NET 3.5

Along with my regular codes are my WSE 1.0 codes. 
I used the VS studio 2008 wizard to convert the codes into 3.5.

I have not made any changes to the WSE 1.0 codes, in terms of changing its references.

is WSE 1.0 compatible with .NET 3.5?

or should i be asking, WSE1 upon conversion to .NET 3.5, does it still work?

Answer (score 1):

Well, are you seeing any problems? The regular WSE classes (thru to WSE3.0) are still in the framework, and are unlikely to be dropped any time soon; you can add new WSE services in VS2008 via "Add Service Reference", "Advanced", "Add Web Reference" (this is a .NET 2.0 web-service client).

There may be some minor differences between the 2.0 web-service reference and the 1.1 equivalent, but you should be OK.

In general though - the trend seems to be to move to WCF (.NET 3.0 and above) web-services. That doesn't mean that you *have* to suddenly change everything; indeed, there is a reasonable amount of ability to use WSE clients against WCF servers and WCF clients against WSE servers (but you need to plan for it in advance).

Comment: ya I'm seeing some problems.

getting errors like these:
Error encountered : WEB_EXCEPTION - System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)


so im just wondering if it is the version of my WSE.
what do you think?

Thank you